Systematically listing outcomes for coin tosses
Following on from this question and it's answers,
I have always listed the outcomes of multiple coin tosses using Mitchell Spector's systematic listing. I would currently explain to students ($11-18$ year-olds) that I tutor, that the way to list these is by the following algorithm: "The next (to the right) letter in the list is $H$ if we have not already listed all the outcomes with $H$ in that place; else the next letter is $T$".
But based on my experience, I think this is poor wording as students often struggle to understand this definition/explanation. My questions are:

What is a better way to word/explain my greedy way of listing the algorithm?

What are alternative ways to describe this way/order of listing the outcomes (other than increasing numbers in binary). In other words, what seemingly different algorithmic definition/rule gives rise to the same ordered list of outcomes?

What are alternative algorithms/ways to list all the possible outcomes from multiples coin tosses? Which ones clearly exhaust all possibilities? mvw's answer answers this question well, although drawing a tree like that also seems time consuming. Are there any ways that are less time consuming but clearly exhaust all the outcomes?


Maybe Mitchell Spector's "counting in binary" is a good one, but I don't know how to explain simply to someone in this age group how this works. When figuring out what $10$ is in binary, I have to think, "what is the least power of two that is less than $10,$ subtract that from $10,$ then continue (So $10$ (base $10$) = $1010$ base $2).$ Then do the same for $11,$ then do the same for $12,$ and so on. But then it will not be obvious to a student that all of these are distinct, and it will not be immediately obvious what this has to do with all the listings of heads and tails.
Also, perhaps this question is better suited to matheducators stackexchange
Edit: Perhaps the explanation starting at around 2:21 in the "harder example" in this video is a good way to demonstrate the systematic listing, as it is the same algorithm as the one I describe above. Maybe I just need to describe it in the simple way like he does, although I then worry that students will not exhaust all possibilities. So I am looking for a way to convince students that they have not missed any possible outcomes or a "checking method" to this end.

Alphabetical order works. Construct the $2^n$ sequences recursively. The sequence starts with H or T. Then following the H you have H or T; same following T. Rinse and repeat.
That prompts the students to leave space between the first H and the first T. In fact, they will soon learn and appreciate that they could just write down $2^{n-1}$ copies of H and of T to start with.
When done, HH...H is first and TT...T is last.
If you then replace H,T by $0,1$ you see the binary representation of the numbers between $0$ and $2^n-1$ in order.
Teach this once and the students can learn much more than how to list all the possibilities.
HH
HH
HT
HT
...
TH
TH
TT
TT
...

Another alternative is to construct the binary tree with H,T as children of the root, then each node has two children similarly labeled. The nodes at level $k$ are the sequences of length $k$ in alphabetical order.
The tree construction generalizes to more complex situations where you don't have the same choices at each node.

So you expect most students to know how to arrange any sequence of words into alphabetical order? Perhaps. I don't get what you mean by your next sentence, "Construct the $2^n$ blocks recursively". Please can you demonstrate this (exactly how you are doing this?).

Yes, I do think my students can alphabetize. I edited the question to change "block" to "sequence". I added a demonstration  and an alternative method.  However you teach this, make it a lesson in more than just listing all the possible outcomes. The method itself is useful.

I don't understand your method. But will re-read it later.

The answer from @paw88789 fleshes out mine.

Not so different than Ethan Bolker's approach, but perhaps a bit less abstract.
I would consider a column-by-column approach:
Of the $16$ outcomes, $8$ will start with heads, and $8$ will start with tails, leading to
$\begin{array}{c} H\\H\\H\\H\\H\\H\\H\\H\\T\\T\\T\\T\\T\\T\\T\\T \end{array}$
Of the $8$ that start with heads, $4$ will have heads next; $4$ will have tails next. Similarly for the $8$ that start with tails, leading to
$\begin{array}{cc} H&H\\H&H\\H&H\\H&H\\H&T\\H&T\\H&T\\H&T\\T&H\\T&H\\T&H\\T&H\\T&H\\T&H\\T&H\\T&H \end{array}$
One sees where this is heading: In the first column, the results have streaks of $8$; in the second column the results have streaks of $4$; in the third column the results will have streaks of $2$; and in the last column, the results will have streaks of $1$:
$\begin{array}{cccc} H&H&H&H\\H&H&H&T\\H&H&T&H\\H&H&T&T\\H&T&H&H\\H&T&H&T\\H&T&T&H\\H&T&T&T\\T&H&H&H\\T&H&H&T\\T&H&T&H\\T&H&T&T\\T&T&H&H\\T&T&H&T\\T&T&T&H\\T&T&T&T \end{array}$
